# Haskell - fast naming of projection functions

Tags: haskell, currying, function-composition, first-class-functions

Suppose I want to define a function `f` in terms of some other predefined function `g` as follows:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f 2 b = g b
f _ _ = 1
```

That is, I want to define the projection, `f(2,_) : Int->Int` to be the same as `g(_) : Int->Int`. Gladly, Haskell has first class functions, and so definitions like the following `squarePlusOne` are valid and standard:

```
plusOne :: Int -> Int
plusOne i = i+1
square :: Int -> Int
square i = i*i
squarePlusOne :: Int -> Int
squarePlusOne = plusOne . Square
```

With Haskell's currying (ie. `f` takes just one `Int` as input and returns an `(Int->Int)` typed function), I am surprised I cannot write

```
f 2 = g
```

Why not? Or is there some other syntax?

Comment: Really, why not? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Oops! I've found that my question was totally founded by a different issue.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, writing `f 2 = g` is a valid way to define `f`. However, when defining functions in this way, remember you must define the whole function with the same pattern signature. That is, you may not exhaust your function by writing

```
f 2 = g
f i j = i+j
```

Instead, this may be achieved like so:

```
f 2 = g
f i = (\j-> i+j)
```

Comment: surely, to match the OP's original definition, the section line should be `f _ = \_ -> 1`? (Oh sorry, I didn't realise you *were* the OP until after I commented :) )

Comment: That's also just `f i = (i +)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `const` function, which creates a function that ignores its argument to return a fixed value.

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f 2 = g            -- f 2 x = g x
f _ = const 1      -- f _ x = const 1 x == (\_ -> 1) x == 1
```